# What are the possibilities for VariantInit Crash in C++?

Tags: c++, com, mfc, initialization, variant

I have variantinit immediately to variantClear like below,

VariantClear(&var);
VariantInit(&var);

VariantInit is crashing in few places and few other places it's not crashing even though I have same sequence in both cases. What could be the reason for VariantInit to fail?

Comment: what have you put into `var` when it crashes ? tried a debugger?

Comment: When debugged from windbg it shows after VariantClear also it contains some values, will it make issue? or what are the possibilities for VariantClear not to clear the var?

Comment: have you checked the return value of variantclear?

Comment: Yes, VariantClear result is S_OK

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's not `VariantClear` that crashes? It's difficult to imagine why `VariantInit` would crash. All it's doing is basically `var.vt = VT_EMPTY;` - not much can go wrong there. I can think of some pretty far-fetched scenarios: say, `var` is actually a global variable exported from a DLL, and the previous `VariantClear` call caused this DLL to be unloaded. On the other hand, it's pretty easy to get `VariantClear` to crash - just give it a variant with an invalid interface pointer (which in turn may be easily caused by a reference counting bug).

Answer (score 0):

You should call `VariantInit()` and then `VariantClear()`

Note: `VariantClear()` can crash if `VARIANT` is not a valid `VARIANT`.